# I cant find the final propaganda mission

Tags: far-cry-4

Anyone having the same problem? I've done all the other propaganda centre missions but cant seem to find the last one. Any suggestions or coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Propaganda Center #1

*Map Coordinates: x:477 y:322*

At this location, and probably every other location for these quests, you will be blowing off your cover as soon as blow up the first item. However, you can take the hills beside the location and snipe down as many of the enemies as you can.

### Propaganda Center #2

*Map Coordinates: x:359 y:577*

This location has a lot of terraced buildings packed together near a mountain. Make sure you have sniped out enough of the enemies from the hill before going all in.

### Propaganda Center #3

*Map Coordinates: x:571 y:778*

It would be better if you reach this location from the north because up here you will get some good sniping spots. Among the enemy crowd, try and take out the rocketeer first, then the sniper and finally the heavy gunner. There also are guards that you can take down with your sniper rifle.

### Propaganda Center #4

*Map Coordinates: x:710 y:709*

Unlike most of the previous locations, this one has the equipment spread out among many huts. You will still stand a better chance if you take down the enemies by sniping at them.

Comment: Thanks...but it still dosnt seem to show up. Must be a glitch.

Comment: I see no point in giving the coordinates, the missions are clearly marked on the map and the target is marked too. Ryan how far are you in the game? IIRC Propaganda center missions are triggered by tearing off propaganda posters enough times

Comment: I've kinda finished the whole campaign missions already. Unless i need more posters cuz i got only 30